# WPF MeasureOverride return value

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing MeasureOverride implementation and there is one point I am kind of stuck.
The return value of the function.
This is the code.

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
Double cHeight = 0.0;
Double cWidth = 0.0;
Size size = new Size(0, 0);

foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
{
    child.Measure(new Size(availableSize.Width, availableSize.Height));
    if (child.DesiredSize.Width > cWidth)
    {
        cWidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;   
    }
    cHeight += child.DesiredSize.Height;    
}

size.Width = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width) ? size.Width : cWidth;
size.Height = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height) ? size.Height : cHeight;

return size;
}
```

My understanding is that returning an empty Size object is an indication that the element will use all the space available. However in this case when the space available is infinite positive, then it is returning zero. 
Should it not be other way around. When infinite space is available then use only the space needed by the child elements? Otherwise constrain itself to use whatever space is available?

```
size.Width = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width) ? cWidth : availableSize.Width;
size.Height = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height) ? cHeight : availableSize.Height;
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is kind of difficult to answer. It depends on what you want to achieve.
Probably you know that the measure phase determins the desired sizes only. The arrange phase fiddles with final values then.

I can imagine a panel with a behavior as in the code above. It could avoid a parent ScrollViewer to reserve too much space in case a child of our panel desires very much space (for example because it is an ItemsControl with many items itself). By returning zero the surrounding ScrollViewer would not reserve this space and in the arrange phase our panel could occupy space as needed although we returned zero.

It would be a very special case, but I was dicussing this very problem with a collegue today when he had a DataGrid along other elements within a ScrollViewer.

Without the code in "Arrange" this is all speculative but it's a possible usage of such code.

Answer (score 1):

With MeasureOverride, you are returning the size that your control wants to be. If MeasureOverride is given infinite bounds then you can make it the size that holds all of the children or not; it is up to you. On the other hand, if you return a size that is larger than you are given, your control parent might accept that and just cut off your control later. For instance, if your control is in a grid and the grid width is set to 500, your MeasureOverride function will get passed an available width of 500. You can return 600 for the width and you will get that 600 width in the ArangeOverride function, but the parent grid will still only give your control 500 width and your content will just get cut off.

I tried this with my own PriorityStackPanel control written for WinRT (Windows 8.1 Store App) and it worked as I described. I think that WPF is just about identical in this case.

In WinRT, there is no "empty" size object. The size object will have some value set for it. NAN and PositiveInfinity both cause exceptions so you really should be returning the size that you want for your control. How you pick that size is up to you but it can't be a "you can decide for me: value like an empty size object (in WinRT). Even if you can return that in WPF, I advise against it since it makes the code less-than-clear. Just return the available size that you were given if that is what you need. Return a larger size if you need more room, but don't expect the container to show all of your content if you ask for more room than it is giving you.